# How to consider first token of splitted string using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8

I am still new to java 8 , I want to convert a loop like this :

```
//result is List<String>
for(String elem:result) {
    if(elem.contains(".")) {
        elem = elem.split("\\.")[0];
    }
}
```

to java 8 stream style .. how can I accomplish this ?

what I tried so far :

```
result.stream().map(String::split("\\.")[0]);
```

but it gives compilation error , and also I don't know how to handle the condition

Comment: what are you alter doing with this `elem`?

Comment: Why do you need streams at all? What's wrong with existing code?

Comment: Your code is not doing anything with `elem`. The optimal solution depends on what your code is actually supposed to do. The statement `if(elem.contains("\\.")) { elem = elem.split("\\.")[0]; }` can be replace with `elem = elem.replaceFirst("\\..*", "");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't compile a pattern for each element (via `split`), but create it before the loop. Also it seems that you want to have a new List as a result, something along the lines:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\.");
 List<String> out = result
            .stream()
            .map(x -> p.splitAsStream(x).findFirst().orElse(x))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

On the other hand if you want to do it in place:

```
 result.replaceAll(x -> p.splitAsStream(x).findFirst().orElse(x));
```

Comment: The result of a split always has a first element.

Comment: @Bohemian agreed, still feels weird to call `get` on an `Optional`

Comment: Well, we *know* that the `orElse(x)` will never be selected, so in Java 10, you could instead do `.orElseThrow(()->new AssertionError("This shouldn't have happened; please sack the programmer."))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of strings (as you say in the code comment) then this is what you want. However, your current code only sets `elem` to the *last* value matching `contains`. It does not create a list.

```
List<String> elems = result.stream()
    .filter(elem -> elem.contains("."))
    .map(elem -> elem.split("\\.")[0])
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The reason that this doesn't compile `result.stream().map(String::split("\.")[0])` is because that's not valid syntax for a method reference. Parentheses after a method reference `String::split(/*anything*/)` is always invalid.

See [the Oracle tutorial on method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) for more info.

Comment: thank u for the info and the link, but for some reason the code returns an empty list ... also I don;t know how will it handle a case when there;s no \\. in the string element

Comment: @osamayaccoub `contains` does not take a regular expression, so no slashes are needed (in which case, your original code was broken). I have updated my answer.

Comment: Not sure if the requirement really is to filter out all elements that don't contain a `.`. The other answers keep the same number of elements in the list.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Well, the other answers have no more information than I do. The code in the OP is effectively no-op and there are no requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `split()` returns the whole String if there’s no separator, you don’t need the `if`, and you can apply the transformation safely to all elements.

You can replace all your code with just this:

```
result.replaceAll(s -> s.split("\\.")[0]);
```

——

Actually, you don’t need to split either: you can use `String#replaceAll()` to remove everything from the first dot onwards instead of splitting:

```
result.replaceAll(s -> s.replaceAll("\\..*", ""));
```

The call to `replaceAll("\\..*", "")` is a no op if there’s no dot in the String.

Comment: Why `replaceAll` and not `replaceFirst`? The pattern `\..*` is already matching everything from the first dot to the end of the string. There can’t be any other occurrences.

Comment: @Holger because they are identical in this case (same performance too) and `replaceAll()` is shorter to type :)

Comment: @Bohemian shorter by 2 letters... how much harm can adding 2 more letters do? reminds me of a convo we had previously...

Comment: @Aominè not much harm, but `replaceAll()` is more general and familiar too, in case someone wants to modify the transform later to something more exotic that removes multiple parts, there’s less to change.

Comment: why don't I need the 'if' ... I mean how is this conversion done safely ? what is the rule?

Comment: @osamayaccoub you don’t need the `if` because if the delimiter is not found, `split()` returns the whole string as the only element in a `String[]`, eg `"foo".split("x")[0]` returns `"foo"`